# how to find that the Android app is 32bit or 64bit

Tags: android, adb

I am new to android. And i don't know how to get the info about android apps.
Can anyone please suggest that how one can find that the android app running is 32bit or 64 bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

APKs are not 32-bit or 64-bit. NDK binaries (`.so` files) inside of APKs will be compiled for specific CPU architectures. Generally, 32-bit binaries should work fine on 64-bit CPUs.

APK is ZIP. You can open it and check directory lib to see which architectures are supported. If there is no directory lib, it supports all architectures.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html